# Loop only executes once C++

Tags: c++, for-loop

I am trying to write a program which  reads 10 integers and then finds and prints the sum of the even and odd integers using for loop.

I saw the previous posts of For loops executing once but they did not help me. Thanks for any help.

Here is my code,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int integer;
    int even = 0;
    int odd = 0;
    int intcount = 0;

    cout << "enter numbers" << endl;
    cin >> integer;


    for(; intcount <= 10; intcount++)
    {

        if((integer % 2) == 0)
        {
            even = even + integer;
        }
        else if((integer % 2) != 0)
        {
            odd = odd + integer;
        }
    }
    cout << "Even sum: " << even << endl;
    cout << "Odd sum: " << odd << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cin>>integer;` should be inside the loop

Comment: I tried that but it still only executes one time, also when I enter a number it multiplies by 11 for some reason

Comment: Why are you comparing `(integer % 2) == 0` twice? Are you afraid `integer` is going to change its value by itself?

Comment: It multiplies by 11 because you read the number once, then add it every time you loop, and you loop 11 times because you go from 0 to 10 included

Comment: if the number is not `even`, then it will be `odd`. You need not do `else if`, just `else` should do

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...). Improve the code to get no warnings. [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) to understand the (buggy) behavior of your program. Improve it, and repeat all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cout<<"enter numbers"<<endl;

for(; intcount < 10; intcount++) // '< 10', not '<= 10' as you start with 0
{
    cin>>integer; // <-- you should read numbers inside the loop

    if(integer % 2 == 0 )
    {
        even += integer; // += is the same as 'even = even + integer'
    }
    else // no 'else if' needed, 'else' is enough
    {
        odd += integer;
    }
}
cout<< "Even sum: " << even<< endl;
cout<< "Odd sum: " << odd<< endl;
```

Comment: Thank you, I see my mistake now. I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Better use a `while` loop with a exit condition and change the code like below:-

```
while(1) 
{
    cout<<"Enter 0 to exit"<<endl;
    cin>>integer; // <-- you should read numbers inside the loop
    if( integer == 0 )
       break;
    else if(integer % 2 == 0 )
    {
        even += integer; // += is the same as 'even = even + integer'
    }
    else
    {
       odd += integer;
    }
 }
```

Comment: `if( integer == 0 ) break;` This is not what OP asked, he/she only want to get 10 numbers that might include zero to.

Comment: Out solution always should not what OP is asking. We should provide a better solution. This kind of operation always should have proper exit option. Sorry disagree with you. Thanks for down vote :-)

Comment: First, I didn't downvote, I never downvote and you can see it in my vote cast records, second, Can you elaborate why `while` loop is better than `for` loop here?

Comment: Because I am using a exit status. You can use a for loop also like `for(;;)`. For loop like this does not look good.

Comment: I mean why you need infinitive loop here? OP wants to get 10 inputs, so a for loop would be the closest solution. In the other hand, using your code user can't insert 0 as input and this might cause OP to add another question when facing this issue. I think it's better not to insist on something you also know that's not correct. Regards.

Comment: You are correct. My answer is just an another option. :-) Its up to him whether follow it or not. Already he accepted a answer so matter is closed I think. I am in office and bit busy may not going to respond to your further queries.